# How to replace current fragment view with another fragment view

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-fragmentactivity, android-listfragment

I have MainActivity as

```
listViewFragment = new ListViewFragment();

    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragmentSensors, listViewFragment).commit();
```

Then I have ListViewFragment and ListViewAdapter class defined which works fine.

```
 listViewSensors.setAdapter(new ListViewAdapter(getActivity(), sensorArray));
```

But when I define onClicklistener current view is not getting replaced by new fragment view.

Here are layout files. 
activity_main

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"  tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <fragment android:id="@+id/fragmentSensors" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="com.testapp.fragment.ListViewFragment"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

listview_fragment

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"  tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ListView android:id="@+id/listViewSensors" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

listview_adapter has imageView and textView.

**And then I defined test_fragment as**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Hello Test"
        android:id="@+id/textViewTest"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**and called it through ListViewFragment as**

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        accelFragment = new AccelFragment();
        testFragment = new TestFragment();

        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentSensors, testFragment).commit();


        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

**But nothing happens, I see Toast pop-up though. If I use android.R.id.content. I see new text on top of current listView items. If I use R.id.listViewSensors I get error** `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View) is not supported in AdapterView`

Comment: Or do I need to extend to Activity and use Intent to call it?

Comment: It seems the problem might be with TestFragment class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OnClickListener does not fire if you have focusable items inside view. I had to add **android:focusable="false"** in activity_main as below.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"  tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    >

    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/fragmentSensors" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="com.skakade.testsensorapp.fragment.ListViewFragment"
        android:focusable="false"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is: you *can't*.

Any fragments you define in the layout file can't be replaced.
You can only replace fragments that were *added dynamically*, i.e. *created* through a FragmentTransaction.

Comment: I created it as getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add...Is this not the right way?

Comment: It's the right way if you're going to use the fragment tag from your layout file.  You don't actually *need* to do it that way.

...with this in your Fragment's class...

     @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_fragments_layout_file, container, false);
    }

You merely dump the <fragment> tag from your layout, assign an id to the RelativeLayout that was it's parent, and then call add() on that id.

Answer (score 0):

Look at code sample @ Google webpage [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html). Search text code for "public static class DetailsFragment **extends Fragment**". You may override method **onCreateView**. It seems you have a problem with the View.